# Trying to Automatically Increase Build Number xCode (Unix Script)

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, unix

I am trying to write a script to automatically increase the xCode build number on each run. The below code however is not working - the build number quickly becomes huge and is currently -9077426947807241788 (!).

Could anyone advise where I am going wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber))
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04d" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

## Update the build date
buildDate=$(date -u +"%T %d %b %Y")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildDate $buildDate" "${SRCROOT}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you script you just need to remove the following line

buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one, its working

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo usage: $0 plist-file
exit 1
fi

plist=$1
dir=$(dirname "$plist")

# Only increment the build number if source files have changed
if [ -n "$(find "$dir" \! -path "*xcuserdata*" \! -path "*.hg" \! -path "*.hgcheck" \! -path "*.hgignore" \! -path "*.hglf" \! -path "Docs/html" -newer "$plist")" ]; then
buildnum=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$plist")
if [ -z "$buildnum" ]; then
echo "No build number in $plist"
exit 2
fi
buildnum=$(expr $buildnum + 1)
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion $buildnum" "$plist"
CFBuildDate=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S o\'clock")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildDate $CFBuildDate" "$plist"
echo "Incremented build number to $buildnum with build date: CFBuildDate"
else
echo "Not incrementing build number as source files have not changed"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below automatically sets the **version** and **short version** string of an Xcode project from the Git repository containing the project.

To use it in Xcode, add the contents to a `Run Script` build phase for your application's target.

#### Script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" != "Release" ]; then

set -o errexit
set -o nounset

# Get info.plist path
INFO_PLIST="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Info"
APP_SHORT_VERSION_PLIST=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"`
DOT="."

# Get git commit number from HEAD's branch
VERSION=$(git --git-dir="${PROJECT_DIR}/.git" --work-tree="${PROJECT_DIR}/" rev-list HEAD | wc -l)

# Trim spaces
VERSION=$(echo "${VERSION}" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')

# Concatenate short version and commit count
VERSION=$APP_SHORT_VERSION_PLIST$DOT$VERSION

# DEBUG
echo "VERSION: ${VERSION}"

# Write to plist
defaults write $INFO_PLIST CFBundleVersion $VERSION

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify if the plist has CFBundleVersion. Else this will give the the wrong number as in your question. Here is my implementation:

```
############
#!/bin/bash
plist="$INFOPLIST_FILE"
dir="$(dirname "$plist")"

buildnum=$(/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$plist")
if [ -z "$buildnum" ]; then
echo "No build number in $plist, set to 1"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :CFBundleVersion string 1" ${plist}
else
buildnum=$(expr $buildnum + 1)
/usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion $buildnum" "$plist"
echo "Incremented build number to $buildnum"

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many "deep" and "authoritative" answers. If I may naively add my two cents:

```
buildNumber=$(printf "%04d" $buildNumber)
#                     ^^^^
#                 output as a *decimal* number with 4 digits left-padded with 0
```

According from what I read two lines above, the build number is expressed in hexadecimal. The right format should be `%04X`.

That missing conversion might explain the observed behavior: as an example, if the current version number is `0010`<sub>16</sub>. You next number is currently `0017`<sub>16</sub> instead of `0011`<sub>16</sub>. And so on (things going wild really fast!)